# How do I achieve implicit conversion of an argument to a parameter using a variant delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to implicitly convert an argument to a parameter instead of explicitly converting the argument using a type cast. The argument is less derived than the parameter, so using a contravariant delegate I expected the argument to be implicitly converted to the parameter. However, the compiler still complains that I need to explicitly convert "object" to "string".

```
public static void Main()
{
DDoSomething<string> doSomething = DoSomething;

object obj = "text";

doSomething(obj);
}

public delegate void DDoSomething<in A>(A str);

public static void DoSomething(string str)
{

}
```

Comment: @TheGeneral `string` derives from `object` =)

Comment: `DoSomething` needs an instance of `string` to be passed into, you can't change this fact with variance.  That is the point of type safety, that compiler will warn you(with error) when you are trying to pass something invalid.

Comment: Also can you please give us more context why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @GuruStron I just corrected that =), I did not type what I was thinking.

Comment: @GuruStron the reason is that sometimes, I find myself passing an object which is actually a string, as an argument to a function whose corresponding parameter is string. It's trivial but I was looking for an alternative to casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a method that expects a string with an object, or more generally, you cannot use a base instance in place of a derived instance.

When you do this:

```
DDoSomething<string> doSomething = DoSomething;
```

`doSomething` is now effectively a method with this signature: `void (string)`.

Contravariance applies to the delegate instance itself, not the arguments:

```
public static void Main()
{
    DDoSomething<object> doSomething = (object obj) => Console.WriteLine(obj);
    
    DDoSomething<string> doSomethinString = doSomething;
    // Using a DDoSomething<object> in place of DDoSomething<string> is legal because of "in"

    doSomethinString("text");
    // This is safe because string is used in place of object (derived in place of base)
}

public delegate void DDoSomething<in A>(A str);
```

Comment: Aah, I see. So to achieve the type of implicit conversion I'm looking for you have to use a reversed assignment compatibility because the method parameters themselves are not variant (due to type safety), it is only the delegates that are variant (i.e. `in` makes the delegate generic type parameter contravariant, not the method parameter). Is this right?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia Yes, that's correct. If you had control over the types you could define an [implicit conversion operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) to avoid casting. With `object` and `string` you will have to cast, or do a `ToString()`.